# The simple unitary fusion categories of multiplicity one

Tags: ct.category-theory, qa.quantum-algebra, subfactors, fusion-categories, unitary-fusion-category

Here are two families of simple unitary [fusion categories](http://www-math.mit.edu/~etingof/egnobookfinal.pdf) of multiplicity one:

- $Vec(C_p)$ with $C_p$ the cyclic group of order $p$ (one or prime),
- The even part of Temperley-Lieb $A_{2n}$ with $n \ge 2$.

Note that the even part of $A_{2n+1}$ admits two simple objects of $\mathrm{FPdim}$ one, so cannot be simple.

**Question**: Should a simple unitary fusion category of multiplicity one be Grothendieck equivalent to one above?

A brute-force classification of simple fusion rings of rank $\le 6$ and multiplicity one provides exactly one extra of rank $5$ (it has type $[[1,1],[\alpha,3],[\beta,1]]$ with $\alpha = 1+\sqrt{2}$ and $\beta = \alpha+1$):

$$\begin{smallmatrix}1&0&0&0&0 \\ 0&1&0&0&0 \\ 0&0&1&0&0 \\ 0&0&0&1&0 \\ 0&0&0&0&1\end{smallmatrix}  ,\  \begin{smallmatrix}0&1&0&0&0 \\ 1&1&1&0&0 \\ 0&1&0&0&1 \\ 0&0&0&1&1 \\ 0&0&1&1&1\end{smallmatrix}  ,\  \begin{smallmatrix}0&0&1&0&0 \\ 0&1&0&0&1 \\ 1&0&1&1&0 \\ 0&0&1&0&1 \\ 0&1&0&1&1\end{smallmatrix}  ,\  \begin{smallmatrix}0&0&0&1&0 \\ 0&0&0&1&1 \\ 0&0&1&0&1 \\ 1&1&0&1&0 \\ 0&1&1&0&1\end{smallmatrix}  ,\  \begin{smallmatrix}0&0&0&0&1 \\ 0&0&1&1&1 \\ 0&1&0&1&1 \\ 0&1&1&0&1 \\ 1&1&1&1&1\end{smallmatrix}
$$

and two extras of rank $6$ (and type $[[1,1],[\alpha,4],[\beta,1]]$ with $\alpha = \frac{3+\sqrt{13}}{2}$ and $\beta = \alpha+1$):

$$\begin{smallmatrix}1&0&0&0&0&0 \\ 0&1&0&0&0&0 \\ 0&0&1&0&0&0 \\ 0&0&0&1&0&0 \\ 0&0&0&0&1&0 \\ 0&0&0&0&0&1\end{smallmatrix}  ,\  \begin{smallmatrix}0&1&0&0&0&0 \\ 1&0&1&1&1&0 \\ 0&1&1&0&0&1 \\ 0&1&0&1&0&1 \\ 0&1&0&0&1&1 \\ 0&0&1&1&1&1\end{smallmatrix}  ,\  \begin{smallmatrix}0&0&1&0&0&0 \\ 0&1&1&0&0&1 \\ 1&1&0&1&1&0 \\ 0&0&1&1&0&1 \\ 0&0&1&0&1&1 \\ 0&1&0&1&1&1\end{smallmatrix}  ,\  \begin{smallmatrix}0&0&0&1&0&0 \\ 0&1&0&1&0&1 \\ 0&0&1&1&0&1 \\ 1&1&1&0&1&0 \\ 0&0&0&1&1&1 \\ 0&1&1&0&1&1\end{smallmatrix}  ,\  \begin{smallmatrix}0&0&0&0&1&0 \\ 0&1&0&0&1&1 \\ 0&0&1&0&1&1 \\ 0&0&0&1&1&1 \\ 1&1&1&1&0&0 \\ 0&1&1&1&0&1\end{smallmatrix}  ,\  \begin{smallmatrix}0&0&0&0&0&1 \\ 0&0&1&1&1&1 \\ 0&1&0&1&1&1 \\ 0&1&1&0&1&1 \\ 0&1&1&1&0&1 \\ 1&1&1&1&1&1\end{smallmatrix}$$

$$\begin{smallmatrix}1&0&0&0&0&0 \\ 0&1&0&0&0&0 \\ 0&0&1&0&0&0 \\ 0&0&0&1&0&0 \\ 0&0&0&0&1&0 \\ 0&0&0&0&0&1\end{smallmatrix}  ,\  \begin{smallmatrix}0&1&0&0&0&0 \\ 1&1&1&0&1&0 \\ 0&1&0&1&0&1 \\ 0&0&1&1&0&1 \\ 0&1&0&0&1&1 \\ 0&0&1&1&1&1\end{smallmatrix}  ,\  \begin{smallmatrix}0&0&1&0&0&0 \\ 0&1&0&1&0&1 \\ 1&0&1&1&1&0 \\ 0&1&1&0&0&1 \\ 0&0&1&0&1&1 \\ 0&1&0&1&1&1\end{smallmatrix}  ,\  \begin{smallmatrix}0&0&0&1&0&0 \\ 0&0&1&1&0&1 \\ 0&1&1&0&0&1 \\ 1&1&0&1&1&0 \\ 0&0&0&1&1&1 \\ 0&1&1&0&1&1\end{smallmatrix}  ,\  \begin{smallmatrix}0&0&0&0&1&0 \\ 0&1&0&0&1&1 \\ 0&0&1&0&1&1 \\ 0&0&0&1&1&1 \\ 1&1&1&1&0&0 \\ 0&1&1&1&0&1\end{smallmatrix}  ,\  \begin{smallmatrix}0&0&0&0&0&1 \\ 0&0&1&1&1&1 \\ 0&1&0&1&1&1 \\ 0&1&1&0&1&1 \\ 0&1&1&1&0&1 \\ 1&1&1&1&1&1\end{smallmatrix}$$

But they can be ruled out from unitary categorification by computing their character table and applying the commutative Schur product criterion ([here](https://arxiv.org/abs/1910.12059v2), Corollary 7.5).

---

*Multiplicity one*:   the fusion coefficients $n_{i,j}^k$ are in $\{0,1\}$.
*Grothendieck equivalent*: the Grothendieck (fusion) rings are equivalent.